# Not able to display data from JSON string on Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, json

I am getting below JSON as my response in Lightning.

```
[{
    "objRecord": {
        "Path_2_Description__c": "• You will complete the program and graduate with a degree/diploma\r\n• This process will take 2 years",
        "Path_3_Description__c": "• Upon graduation, get a degree/diploma, become eligible for post-graduation work permit\r\n• Work on Student Visa\r\n• Apply for post-graduation jobs and work\r\n• Find an Employer who can sponsor PR visa\r\n• This process will take 2 years",
        "Option_Code_Name__c": "Study,Work only and Return to India",
        "Path_1_Description__c": "• You will need to apply for admission from India to Canada and this will take 3 months to get an admission\r\n• Apply for a student visa from India to Canada. This process will take 3 months\r\n• Once you get a visa, you can travel to Canada and join the college",
        "Option_Code__c": "S-002 CAN",
        "Path_3__c": "Apply for post graduation jobs and work",
        "Path_2__c": "Attend College",
        "Id": "a4D590000008PmbEAE",
        "Path_1__c": "Apply for a Student VISA"
    },
    "icon": "utility:chevronright",
    "display": false,
    "rows": [{
        "**path**": "Apply for a Student VISA",
        "**description**": "• You will need to apply for admission from India to Canada and this will take 3 months to get an admission\r\n• Apply for a student visa from India to Canada. This process will take 3 months\r\n• Once you get a visa, you can travel to Canada and join the college"
    }, {
        "**path**": "Attend College",
        "**description**": "• You will complete the program and graduate with a degree/diploma\r\n• This process will take 2 years"
    }, {
        "**path**": "Apply for post graduation jobs and work",
        "**description**": "• Upon graduation, get a degree/diploma, become eligible for post-graduation work permit\r\n• Work on Student Visa\r\n• Apply for post-graduation jobs and work\r\n• Find an Employer who can sponsor PR visa\r\n• This process will take 2 years"
    }],
    "size": 3,
    "width": "1rem"
}]
```

I wanted to show the data in "path" and "description" (highlighted) in lightning component. I have tried in the following way but I see no data returning on component.

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.mainRecords.rows.path}" var="mainRec">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-6">
            {!mainRec}
         </div>
    </aura:iteration>
</div>
```

Can someone help me with this. Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer `[]` means this is an array. You need two iterators:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.mainRecords}" var="record">
  <aura:iteration items="{!record.rows}" var="mainRec">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-6">
      {!mainRec}
     </div>
  </aura:iteration>
</aura:iteration>
```

Any time you have an array in your data structure, you're going to have an `aura:iteration` to display those values.

Comment: Thanks. It worked...